# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Firefox works. Chrome not

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

The last js function in this document(refreshuserinfo) works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome an Safari it doesn't work.

The console shows me: 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: refreshuserinfo is not defined**  and **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

i've got no idee why this function doen't work in these Browsers

```
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0,  user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,100,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="meldung"></div>
        <div class="logo">
            Quiz
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper-menu">
            <div id="element">
                <div id="element2"></div>
                <!--Hier wird das JSON eingefügt-->
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-menu-inner">
                <hr>
                <a onclick="shuffle()" href="#"><div>Spielen</div></a>
                <a href="kategorien.html"><div>Kategorie wählen</div></a>
                <a href="#" onclick="randomCategory()"><div>Zufällige Kategorie spielen</div></a>
                <hr>
                <a href="editor_category.html"><div>Kategorie erstellen</div></a>
                <a href="editor_question.html"><div>Frage erstellen</div></a>
                <a href="#" onclick="logout()"><div>Abmelden</div></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    function refreshuserinfo() {
        $('#refresher').addClass("fa-spin");
        setTimeout(function()$('#refresher').removeClass('fa-spin'),3000);
        $.ajax ({
                url:'http://marcelkipp.com/quizapp/userinfo.php?user_id='+localStorage.getItem('user_id'),
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'get',
                cache: false,
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log('JSON erfolgreich ausgelesen!');
                    var category = data.category_title;
                    if (category==null) category = "Keine Kategorie gewählt";
                    localStorage.setItem('points', data.points);
                    localStorage.setItem('total_questions',data.number_pq);
                    $('#element2').empty();
                    $('#element2').append("<a href='#'><div class='menu_username nopointer'>"+localStorage.points+"&nbsp;Punkte</div></a>"+
                    "<a href='#'><div class='menu_username nopointer'>"+localStorage.total_questions+"&nbsp;gespielte Fragen</div></a>")
                }
            });
    }
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no need to use multiple `<script> </script>` block, use only one and keep all functions inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
setTimeout(function()$('#refresher').removeClass('fa-spin'),3000);
```

Missing pair of curly braces, should be:

```
setTimeout(function () {$('#refresher').removeClass('fa-spin');}, 3000);
```

The fix fixes both errors. `refreshuserinfo()` was undefined, since reference error broke the code.

Comment: sometimes it could be so easy